# Please help me fix this PHP while statement

Tags: php, debugging, while-loop

The script below is supposed to end when the "best match" is found in a string, but even though I know it eventually is found the script keeps on running.  Please help me fix my error.

```
$end = "1";
while ($end != 2) {
foreach($anchors as $a) { 
    $i = $i + 1;
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');


        //if ($i<80) {
    //if (strpos($item, ".$array.") == false) {


    //}
      if (strpos($text, "best match") == true) {
$end = "2";
}
   if (strpos($text, "by owner") === false) {
       if (strpos($text, "map") === false) {
   if ($i > 17) {

     echo "<a href =' ".$href." '>".$text."</a><br/>";

}
   }

   }

    }
        //$str = file_get_contents($href);
//$result = (substr_count(strip_tags($str),"ipod"));
//echo ($result);



}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Why is `$end` a string that can either be `"1"` or `"2"` and is compared against an integer? Why not just make it a boolean? Why not just use `break 2`? If the result of `strpos` is `0`, it will not compare as equal to `true` (a pointless comparison anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `strpos`, you're comparing with *true*, and this is wrong.
Also, in thas **if** statement you should break the foreach and the while loop.

This is the right code:

```
<?php

while ($end != 2) {

  foreach($anchors as $a) {
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');

    if (strpos($text, "best match") !== false) {
      $end = "2"; 
      break 2;
    }

    if (strpos($text, "by owner") === false) {
      if (strpos($text, "map") === false) {
        if ($i > 17) {
          echo "<a href =' ".$href." '>".$text."</a><br/>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nested loops. You need also need to end the foreach loop when you find 'best match'. Try:

```
if (strpos($text, "best match") == true) {
    $end = 2; 
    break; # Terminate execution of foreach loop
}
```

Comment: no this doesn't work ):

Comment: @scoota269 . I think it should be `break 2;` to exit from both `foreach` and `while`